# XSLT: Verify if sibbling nodes have the same IDREF attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd, idref

Good afternoon.

I'm fairly new to XML, XSD and XSLT and i'm facing the following issue:
I have the following substructure in XSD, that can occur multiple times, which is part of a far larger structure which is irrelevant and i won't include for the sake of clarity:

```
<xs:complexType name= "listavotosmocao">
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="favor" type="pessoaref"/>
    <xs:element name="contra" type="pessoaref"/>
    <xs:element name="abstiveram" type="pessoaref"/>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="pessoaref">
<xs:attribute ref="id" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Using XLST i'm supose to asure that if an element has a certain IDREF attribute value any repetition of the same value on the other elements should trigger a message on the stdout.
To achieve this end i wrote the following lines in XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="votacao//favor">
   <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::contra[attribute::ref= ./@ref])
   + count(following-sibling::contra[attribute::ref=./@ref]) )> 0">
        Error
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which always prints Error in the html file, instead of doing so only when there are elements with the same values on IDREF.
Both my understanding of the language and my search have not been able to help me understand this issue and how to solve it.
Any ideas to why this might occur?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attribute::ref= ./@ref
```

is the same as @ref=@ref so is true whatever value of ref,

I'm not sure about the relevance of the XSD fragment (which doesn't mention ref) but perhaps you want

```
<xsl:if test="../contra[@ref=current()/@ref][2]">
    Error
</xsl:if>
```

That tests if there are 2 (or more contra elements with the same ref as the current favor element, perhaps you want [1] or to use ../* rather than ../contra, it all depends. The question is not clear enough to be certain.

Comment: I'm sorry i might have not explained myself properly. English is not my native language and i'm not fully aware of what would and wouldn't be useful to present the problem.
The ref is present in the "pessoaref" complex type, which all three elements are of.
This does solve my issue perfectly though. Much obliged.
I assume that current()/@ref returns the ref attribute of the current favor element i'd be cicling through, correct?

Comment: @rieper22 yes current() is the node that was the current node at the _start_ of the xpath (unlike `.` which changes meaning in each step)

Comment: couldn't pick that up neither from my class nor from w3schools.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1) try `&lt;` instead of `>`

2) in `for-each` you are looping through `favor` elements, in `if` you are counting `contra` elements, hope that's what you really want

3) why count preceding and following sibling, couldn't that be in all at once like

```
<xsl:if test="count(../contra[@ref = ./@ref]) &lt; 0">
```

Comment: How can a count of elements ever be less than 0?

Comment: and `@ref = ./@ref` is `@ref = @ref` which isn't a very interesting test